# iOS : How to properly use Size Classes (or other solution) to have different portrait and landscape layouts?

Tags: ios, orientation, ios-autolayout, size-classes

So far my application only handles landscape orientation, and now I want it to also handle portrait orientation. 
Almost all the views should end up having very different layouts depending on the orientation, so I thought first of creating another Storyboard and assign it each of them to a specific orientation. But from everything I read from here, it looks like it’s not the right thing to do.

Here is the layout I want to have:

[image]

So I tried to use Size Classes instead, but I’m very confused about how it works. For example, I tried this from this existing layout:

```
final class TestCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtextLabel: UILabel!
}
```

[image]

Changing the orientation, clicking “Vary for traits” based on width, and updating the layout with "Done Varying",

[image]

But now when I want to save this, and come back to landscape mode, I end up having the same layout for both orientations:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Vary for Traits again...

- Do your portrait layout `wC hR` first
- then view in landscape mode
- you're now in `wC hC`
- click Vary for Traits, and select **`Height`** (width is still `wC`)
- modify your constraints... delete the ones that won't apply to this layout, add new ones that will apply
- Done

That *should* give you what you want.

Comment: Ok I got it know! I actually didn't understand how regular/compact worked, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can use `UIStackView`,

In `Portrait` mode[w**C** h**R**], keep `UIStackView` axis to `Vertical` and in `Landscape` mode[w**C** h**C**], it should be `Horizontal`

[image: Portrait][image: Landscape][image: alighnment]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For this precise case I could indeed use a `UIStackView`, but I also have much more complex views in my app where using a `UIStackView` would not be enough.